# One entry missing in the channel-video list when sorting by popularity

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

When sorting the videos in [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ) by [`Most popular`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid) there are only 7 videos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7UrY.png

But when sorting by [`Date added (oldest)`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ/videos?view=0&sort=da&flow=grid) there are 8 videos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvvJf.png

Same for sorting by [`Date added (newest)`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid): https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAk1v.png

Is this a bug in the YouTube UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fixed now:

- by [`Most popular`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVADi.png
- by [`Date added (oldest)`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ/videos?view=0&sort=da&flow=grid): https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlUsV.png
- by [`Date added (newest)`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj1VqrHhDte54oLgPG4xpuQ/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGZ6.png

Maybe I just was "lucky" to experience some effect coming from [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`